# HyperlinkedRelatedField doesn't work in drf-nested-routers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I'm using drf-nested-routers as below

```
calendar_router = DefaultRouter()
calendar_router.register(r'calendars', views.CalendarViewSet, base_name='calendars')

event_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(calendar_router, r'calendars', lookup='calendar')
event_router.register(r'events', views.EventViewSet, base_name='events')
```

When I add `url` field to `Calendar` serializer, it works well, but when add `url` field to 'Event' serializer, it just raise below exception

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "event-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in
>   your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
event_router.register(r'events', views.EventViewSet, base_name='events')
```

with

```
event_router.register(r'events', views.EventViewSet, base_name='event')
```